# Select last row from a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, vba, spring-boot, ms-access

I have a query that returns some dates which are not in any order. I need to select the last row from the sub query. The problem is all the solutions I can find online uses something like

```
ORDER BY qry_doc_dates.arrival_date DESC LIMIT 1

Select qry_doc_dates.arrival_date 
FROM (qry_doc_date) AS qry_doc_dates 
ORDER BY qry_doc_dates.arrival_date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

which will not serve my purpose because it first orders the dates as DESC(or ASC).

Suppose the qry_doc_date returns :

```
"2019-05-27",
"2019-05-13",
"2019-05-20",
"2019-05-22",
"2019-07-12",
"2019-05-22",
"2019-07-16",
"2019-05-22"
```

As we can see that the returned values are not in order. If I use

```
ORDER BY qry_doc_dates.arrival_date DESC LIMIT 1
```

then it returns "2019-07-16" But I need "2019-05-22" which is the last row.

EDIT 1:
I am trying to convert this VBA query to MYSQL.

```
DLast("arrival_date", "qry_doc_date", "[package_id] = " & Me!lstPackage)
```

I suppose I misunderstood what the VBA query wants to return. Another issue is I do not have means to run this VBA query and check the result myself.

Comment: Tables aren't order sets. What today is the last row, can be different next second based on how the db bring the data. You can't say what is the last row unless you use `ORDER BY`, Do you have an ID to tell you what is the last row?

Comment: Apparantly not at this point. The query "qry_doc_date" that I mentioned further includes multiple sub-query in hierarchy that ultimately drops down to a table "tbl_voyage" that has an ID and this column arrivalDate. Should I bring that ID here ? Also, a doubt, Do you mean that I might get different results every time I run this query ?

Comment: why not just `Select MAX(qry_doc_dates.arrival_date)`?

Comment: @Alex Just tried this. It also returns the same result.

Comment: That is impossible, untill you have some invisible characters somewhere in strings

Comment: By same result, I mean the MAX date value from the list of dates.

Comment: `But I need "2019-05-22"` Why you need that 22? What not 20 give us some context on what are you trying to do. btw you also have two 22 on that data.

Comment: I need this date because the VBA query I am trying to convert to mysql query has the `DLast` function which selects the last row from the returned values. I have mentioned that query in the EDIT 1. I have the list of dates returned but I am stuck at trying to understand what `DLast` wants (the last row as much as I have understood) and thats why I am trying to get the last returned row. The two same dates you mentioned are the part of the legacy database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to in *qry_doc_date* to include a [sequential row number](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).

Then you can use something like this:

```
ORDER BY qry_doc_dates.row_number DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think your answer will produce the required result that I need. I will try this in a day or two and update here marking it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Please upvote the question if you feel it was useful enough as many people didn't know about this row_number() function in mysql 8.0

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Your question doesn't make too much sense according to the SQL standard. In the absense of an `ORDER BY` clause the database engine is free to return the rows in *any* order. This order may even change over time.

**So essentially you are requesting the "last random row" the query returns**. If this is the case, why don't you get the "first random row"? It doesn't make any difference, does it?

The only way of getting the last random row is to get them all and discard all of them except for the last one.

Now, if you just need **one random row**, I would suggest you just get the first random row, and problem solved.

Comment: You are correct. I think I mis-understood what the VBA query wants me to return. I have edited my question. Please have a look again.

Answer (score 2):

In response to the additional information from your edit:

> EDIT 1: I am trying to convert this VBA query to MYSQL.
>
> ```
> DLast("arrival_date", "qry_doc_date", "[package_id] = " & Me!lstPackage)
> ```
>
> I suppose I misunderstood what the VBA query wants to return. Another
>   issue is I do not have means to run this VBA query and check the
>   result myself.

Unless your dataset `qry_doc_date` is ordered by means of an `order by` clause, the `DFirst` or `DLast` domain aggregate functions will return essentially a random record.

This is stated in the [MS Access Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/dfirst-dlast-functions-adb06169-bf49-4f80-bf04-1e4b5a48a8a7) for these two functions:

> You can use the `DFirst` and `DLast` functions **to return a random record** from a particular field in a table or query when you simply need any value from that field.
>
> **[ ... ]**
>
> If you want to return the first or last record in a set of records (a domain), **you should create a query sorted as either ascending or descending** and set the TopValues property to 1. For more information, see the TopValues property topic. From a Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) module, you can also create an ADO Recordset object and use the MoveFirst or MoveLast method to return the first or last record in a set of records.

Comment: I believe this DLast function is added to the code because one entry was made somewhere in the corresponding table just before executing this function. This date is being retrieved to set it to another function. This is how the other developer did the code. I have confirmed that the last entry of date is required and I understand that it will become obsolete just after making another entry in that table.